# Installing Bosun component in on VM or in several VMs

Tags: fiware, fiware-bosun

I would like to use the Bosun GE by my own but it is not clear if I could install the 2 components of this GE (fiware-facts and fiware-cloto) into different VM or they can be installed in the same VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can install Fiware Bosun in both ways.

By default configure files are written to work in the same VM, so if you install all required software in the same VM everything will works perfectly.

If you want to distribute fiware-facts and cloto in two different VM, you must configure the IP address in both components:

- Fiware-cloto config file:

> cloto: {{Fiware-Cloto-Public-IP}} (example: 83.53.21.33)
>
> rabbitMQ: RabbitIP

- Fiware-facts config file:

> NOTIFICATION_URL: http://{{Fiware-Facts-Public-IP}}:5000/v1.0
>
> RABBITMQ_URL: RabbitIP

In addition, Note that MYSQL could also be installed into a different VM, so you should edit `mysql host` too in order to provide the IP address where Database is installed in both configuration files (fiware-cloto and fiware-facts)